# Download cycle maps with downloadosmtiles.pl

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm using the script **downloadosmtiles.pl** to download tiles from opencyclemap but the tile I got are not from cycle map, but a classic open street map. 
Here is an example of the command line I'm using :

```
downloadosmtiles.pl --link='http://www.opencyclemap.org/?lat=42.8&lon=0.1&zoom=10'--baseurl="http://tile.opencyclemap.org/" --zoom=10:12
```

Am I requesting the good link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in there (missing space before --baseurl) and you're using an incomplete baseurl.

This should do it:

```
downloadosmtiles.pl --link='http://www.opencyclemap.org/?lat=42.8&lon=0.1&zoom=10' --baseurl='http://tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle' --zoom=10:12
```

Comment: Great!! it works, I had also to change double-cotes by simple cote under baseurl

Comment: Where can I find to download this script?

Comment: It's OK i found it.. for any other looking for this script it can be downloaded here:
http://search.cpan.org/~rotkraut/Geo-OSM-Tiles-0.02/downloadosmtiles.pl